# Is it OK to use multiple indications which depicts the same thing?

Tags: user-behavior

From the suggestion of my previous post ([here](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/105988/how-to-show-a-very-important-notification-on-the-button-itself-which-opens-it)),

the message button i'm using :

[image]

Here the stars and the notification (1) both depicts a new message.
So is it OK to use both of them or the either one?

PS: the message will always be (1) at a given time for now.There can't be 2 new messages.I just added the badge to make it more prominent.

**Update**

Basically the messages are received from a single person *every time*. This makes the message somewhat special (just to justify the stars).

**Also**, the user will *only* open the app to read a message which is sent by the same person every time.

Comment: Only when your app is build for a Disco Theme :) *Kidding*... I guess the stars are not needed.

Comment: @Dipak The stars or the badge?

Comment: @Dipak please look at my updated too.

Comment: I am sorry @joeyrohan but I don't really understand why you went for the "stars". It doesn't provide a clear message to me.

Comment: @DimitraMiha please look at my update

Comment: @joeyrohan clear, but it doesn't really communicate "special" to me. It would be a good case for testing though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting aside the fact that I do not like this kind of "glitter" effect I think it is fine as long as they form one compound effect, and it looks like they do in this case, as they are shown in the same place. Should they appear in different places, it might be confusing.

However, regarding the number in the badge, it is misleading if you display (1) when there are many notifications. Instead, you could display simply a disc including a dot, something similar to what Slack does:

[image]

It is not perfect, but at least the number is not misleading.

Comment: Totally agree. If the number does not show the true number of messages, it should be a symbol instead.

Comment: I have just made an update to justify the glitters

Comment: Well, every app has its own story to tell. If this fits the story, then why not?

Comment: How distracting would it be seeing the constantly blinking stars on screen when you have no intention of reading the notification in given moment?

Comment: @Dipak the user will *only* open the app to read a single message.I don't know if it still justifies

Comment: @Dipak - I really get your point. On the other hand, my daughter uses a social app for kids where a lot of things are just... different than I would ever recommend. But together they form a really interesting product.

Comment: @joeyrohan - if User opens the app just to read this one message, maybe it should be the message view that opens automatically?

Comment: That's what I said - the theme would matter. If the app requires glitters, do add or else they can be expensive to your business.

Comment: @DominikOslizlo the user has a option to send message too (should have mentioned that) and I want to make user little impatient to get to the message and then open it like a blast (yes, it is that important for a user)

Comment: OK, got it. As I said, every app tells some story, design should support that, building up the emotions around it. If you say it is important, I understand.

Comment: The glitters look like the 21st century version of a blink tag.

Comment: If the glitters are looking awful, I can happily remove it @KenMohnkern @ dominik

Comment: They can still serve the purpose :)

Comment: I mean everyone is pointing too much about the glitters.Kinda makes me wonder :/

Comment: Yes, but still, look at this one for example, it is the social app I mentioned before: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.watagame.skymo - it is different, breaks some of the design rules, yet it has really good reviews just because it fits the audience.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using the animation of the glitter as a way to draw the user's eye to that area of the screen. Right? Does it have to be a constant glitter effect, or could it play and then have a "resting" state with just the red dot?

The biggest thing to consider is if your user base is one familiar with most popular apps using the red dot pattern, you may not need much more. If users have a message, whether it's starting with 1 for now (seemingly) and growing to more or not, using the red dot would establish a known paradigm you don't need to update/change with the next iteration.